# How to dispatch redux action inside fetch interceptor?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch, redux-saga

Hi I am having a fetch interceptor to catch some common responses like 401 etc... When response status is equal to 401. I need to dispatch logout action inside the interceptor itself. But i am not able to make it. Dispatch action is not working. Here i am sharing the code of what i have done . Please help me to fix that.

```
import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';
import { pushToDataLayer } from './GTMUtility';
import configureStore from '../redux/configureStore';
import { LoggedOut } from "../redux/auth/actions";


const getEndPointFromURL = (url = '') => {
    if (!url) return;
    const urlSegments = url.split('/')
    return urlSegments[urlSegments.length - 1];
}

const store = configureStore();

export const interceptor = fetchIntercept.register({
    request: function (url, config) {
        return [url, config];
    },

    requestError: function (error) {
        // Called when an error occured during another 'request' interceptor call
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },

    response: function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            store.dispatch(LoggedOut());
            return false
        }
        return response;
    },

    responseError: function (error) {
        // Handle an fetch error
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

**Exporting Store:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { fromJS } from "immutable";

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  const composeEnhancers =
    typeof window === "object" && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
      })
      : compose;

  return {
    ...createStore(
      rootReducer,
      composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
    ),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see `const store = configureStore();` but you're not exporting store, are you creating multiple stores?

Comment: now i exported store. But no luck

Comment: Show us how you export/import store and the `configureStore` function

Comment: i have edited my question. On how i am exporting configureStore

Answer (score 0):

In your interception register file, you must also export that store for other files to use it. If you also call `const store = configureStore()` somewhere else, that’s creating a totally new instance of store. Then the `store.dispatch` used by interceptor is not gonna affect the other instance of store, thus your problem.

I suggest that, instead of exporting `configureStore` function, you create the store right inside that file and export it.

```
export const store = configureStore()
```

Then in the interceptor file:

```
import { store } from '../redux/configureStore';
```

Same to other files that need a store. Don’t create it again.